# Find countries by a user to city relationship where a user is related to all cities of a country

Tags: mysql, sql, doctrine-orm, orm, dql

I have four tables: User, Country, Region and City

Country has many Regions which has many Cities.

A user can be related to 0-to-many Cities (wish to visit).

How can I write a MySQL query (or DQL) that finds out Regions and Countries that a user is **fully** related to them, i.e wish to visit **ALL** of their Cities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `NOT EXISTS` and `LEFT JOIN`

```
SELECT *
FROM Region r
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
   SELECT 1 
   FROM City c
   LEFT JOIN User u ON c.id_city = u.id_city and u.id_user = 'user_id'
   WHERE c.id_reg = r.id_reg and u.id_user IS NULL
)
```

This will find only regions where user wish to visit all cities, however, if you want countries it is just a slight modification

```
SELECT *
FROM Country ctr
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
   SELECT 1 
   FROM Region r
   LEFT JOIN City c ON r.id_reg = c.id_reg
   LEFT JOIN User u ON c.id_city = u.id_city and u.id_user = 'user_id'
   WHERE ctr.id_country = r.id_country and u.id_user IS NULL
)
```

Answer (score 1):

For Region, it would be easy to compare the number of cities against the maximum number of cities

```
SELECT user_id,
 Region_count.region_id
FROM User
JOIN 
(SELECT user_id, region_id, count(*) as reg_user_count
 FROM City
 WHERE user_id='ThisUser'
 GROUP BY region_id) Region_Count
  ON Region_Count.user_id=User.user_id 
JOIN 
(SELECT region_id, count(*) as reg_max
 FROM City
 GROUP BY region_id) as Region_Max
 ON Region_Max.region_id=Region_Count.region_id 
   AND Region_Max.reg_max=Region_Count.reg_user_count
 WHERE user_id='ThisUser'
```

You can do the same against country. Let me know if you can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Start at the `User` level.  Then join in to ever-larger entities, and use distinct to cut down on duplicates.

```
SELECT distinct
  u.user_name
  ,r.region_name
  ,co.country_name
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN cities c ON u.wish_to_visit = c.city_name
LEFT JOIN regions r ON c.region = r.region_name
LEFT JOIN countries co ON r.country = co.country_name
WHERE u.user_name = 'John Doe'
```

**Edit: finding only countries where the user wants to visit ALL**

Post question update, let's only pull in countries where the user wants to visit ALL cities therein.  In this case, we start from Countries and work our way down to Users.  Then we aggregate to see what percentage of a country's cities are captured.

The key is to only join in the user we care about (not to filter by them though, that will eliminate `NULL`, where the user does not match a city).  After all that, a simple `HAVING` will help us filter for only countries with an entirety match.

```
SELECT
  c.country_name
  ,count(ci.city_name) as count_all_cities
  ,count(u.wish_to_visit) as count_user_cities
FROM countries c
LEFT JOIN regions r ON c.country_name = r.country
LEFT JOIN cities ci ON r.region_name = ci.region
LEFT JOIN users u ON ci.city_name = u.wish_to_visit AND u.user_name = 'John Doe'
GROUP BY c.country_name
HAVING count(ci.city_name) = count(u.wish_to_visit)
```

Comment: Did you realize that I need countries a user wishes to visit **ALL** their cities and not **ONE OF** their cities ?

Comment: @MedUnes I did not.  Updated to reflect the change.

Answer (score 0):

Use the joins

```
select cu.country_name, r.region_name from User u join City c
on u.cityID=c.cityID join Region r on
c.regionID=r.regionID join Country cu
on r.countryID=cu.countryID
where u.userID=SOMEID
```

Comment: this will include countries that have even **one single** city in the wishlist

Comment: so for this you can use a filter such as where clause `where u.userID=SOMEID`

Comment: Can you define the schema of the table in your question it will help